Error with PartitionKey in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using Audit.NET and Azure Storage Table
I've been working on implementing an Audit Trail in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, utilizing the Audit.NET library, specifically with the AzureStorageTableDataProvider for storing audit events. The library's documentation can be found here:
https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WebApi/README.md
I'm encountering an issue when setting up the connection to Azure Table Storage. Here's the relevant part of my setup:
public void AuditSetupOutput(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };

    Configuration.Setup()
        .JsonSystemAdapter(options)
        .UseAzureTableStorage(config => config
            .Endpoint(new Uri("https://account.table.core.windows.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential())
            .TableName(evt => $"{_TargetTableName}{DateTime.UtcNow:MMMyyyy}")
            .ClientOptions(new TableClientOptions { Retry = { MaxRetries = 3 } })
            .EntityBuilder(builder => builder
                .PartitionKey(auditEvent => auditEvent.EventType)
                .RowKey(auditEvent => Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))
                .Columns(col => col
                    .FromDictionary(auditEvent => new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "EventType", auditEvent.EventType },
                        { "UserName", auditEvent.Environment.UserName },
                        { "EventDuration", auditEvent.Duration },
                        { "DataSize", auditEvent.ToJson().Length },
                        { "Data", auditEvent.ToJson().Length >= 32000 ? CompressAuditEventData(auditEvent.ToJson()) : auditEvent.ToJson() }
                    })));

    var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnScopeCreated, scope =>
    {
        scope.SetCustomField("TraceId", httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.TraceIdentifier);
    });
}

When I validate this setup, I receive the following error related to the PartitionKey:

The 'PartitionKey' parameter of value 'GET:https://demoapi.azurewebsites.net/api/product/23' is out of range with RequestId:adb38aea-c002-0061-436d-d408ff000000
Time:2024-07-12T15:08:43.7480899Z
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: OutOfRangeInput
Content:
{ "odata.error":{"code":"OutOfRangeInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The 'PartitionKey' parameter of value 'GET:https://demoapi.azurewebsites.net/api/product/23' is out of range.\nRequestId:adb38aea-c002-0061-436d-d408ff000000\nTime:2024-07-12T15:08:43.7480899Z"}}}

It appears that the PartitionKey value is being rejected. Does anyone have insights on why this might be happening or how to resolve this issue?
Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

keys are normally rejects if you try to add duplicate keys.  You are getting a status of 400 and error code "OutOfRange" which means the type of data in a column does not agree with the try in the database.  It looks like duration should be a time not a DataTime.

The reason you are getting this error is because you are setting your PartitionKey value as GET:https://demoapi.azurewebsites.net/api/product/23 which contains an invalid character (/).
To fix this error, please set a valid value for the PartitionKey. Please see this link for the list of disallowed characters in PartitionKey and RowKey in Table Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#characters-disallowed-in-key-fields.
